# Multiple select (drop down list) Laravel using Laravel Collective

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravelcollective

Hey guys I have a project-create form where I want an the ability to select multiple users for a project

So far I've achieved this much:

```
Hey guys, so here's my code and what I want is different

<div class="form-group">
 <strong>User :</strong>
   <br/>
    @foreach($users as $value)
     <label>{{ Form::checkbox('user[]', $value->id, false, 
    array('class'=>'name')) }}
            {{ $value->name }}
     </label>
   <br/>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

My ProjectController.php

```
 public function create()
  {
    //
    $users = User::all();

    return view('admins.projects.create', compact('users'));
  }
```

Now this works just fine, the thing is I get multiple checkboxes and it's messy.

I'm using Admin LTE and I want to use the following html snippet instead of Checkbox code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Multiple</label>
      <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data- 
 placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;">
       <option>Alabama</option>
       <option>Alaska</option>
       <option>California</option>
       <option>Delaware</option>
       <option>Tennessee</option>
       <option>Texas</option>
       <option>Washington</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

This design is a better and less messy alternate to checkboxes.
I am not able to make it work by changing it to

```
LaravelCollective docs:
Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), null, 
array('multiple' => true));
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something I always use is:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-12">
     {!! Form::label('users[]', 'Role') !!}
     {!! Form::select('users[]',$users,  null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple']) !!}
 </div>
```

Where you have to hold the CTRL button to select multiple users. The [] is important because php otherwise will not reconize the input as an array.

If you want something more fancy you can try something like this: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll try bootstrap-multiselect